# BitmapFactory shows OutOfMemoryError when reading all images from sdcard0

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to retrieve all the images from the sdcard0 by using adapter - getView() method. I'm trying to populate a gallery view, which is deprecated but the requirements document imply that I use gallery view. As i see, if there are very few images then this approach works but if a number like more than 10 or so images on sdcard0 then I get OutOfMemoryException. Can someone help me to reuse the memory for Bitmap object that I'm reading from file and creating

```
"Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile((file.getPath())), 275, 210);".
```

Since I'm creating a lot of Bitmap objects I'm running out of memory. The images are all of jpg format, clicked using the on device camera and size averaging at 3.5 MB. Its a Samsung Galaxy S4 on which i'm testing.

```
Button btnFetch;
ImageView ivLoad;
Gallery galView;
MyAdapter adapter;
static Context context;
File[] files;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sdcard);
    context = SDCardActivity.this;
    btnFetch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFetch);
    ivLoad = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivLoad);
    galView = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.galView);

    loadingMyGalleryView();
    adapter = new MyAdapter();
    galView.setAdapter(adapter);

    galView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            File file = files[position];
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
            ivLoad.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    });
}

private void loadingMyGalleryView() {
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        // It have to be matched with the directory in SDCard
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "DCIM/Camera");
        boolean exist = f.exists();
        Log.d("loki", "Reached Line 80" + exist);
        if (exist) {
            Log.d("loki", "Reached line 82");
            files = f.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                Log.d("loki", "" + files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return files[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Log.d("loki", ""+files.length);
        return files.length;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
        File file = files[position];
        Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile((file.getPath())), 275, 210);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        return image;
    }
}
```

LogCat shows:

```
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:302)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:328)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at com.example.sdcard.SDCardActivity$MyAdapter.getView(SDCardActivity.java:140)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2313)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-10 12:15:38.403: E/AndroidRuntime(21585):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your adapter is broken as you do not correctly handle `convertView` (if fact you do nothing here) therefore for each row you create new view instead of reusing existing ones which consumes memory. I.e.:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null){
       // Inflate View from xml or create by code
       v = .....
    }

    // display your thumbnail
    ....
}
```

Here is reading: http://android-decoded.blogspot.com/2011/12/so-what-exactly-is-convertview.html

Answer (score 0):

In `getView()` reuse the second argument i.e convertView to save the memory for your application.
 [to read more documentation click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)